# Encrypt multiple files GNUPG

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I'm new on stackoverflow, and i need your help)
I'll try to describe the situation.
On a windows file-server, I have a task (running every 10 minutes) that decrypt gpg files received from an external trusted source (which encrypt files using my public key). The task run using a domain account, and decrypt files using my private key of course. Here is the script that I use to decrypt multiple files:

```
@echo off
FOR /R L:\IN\ %%f in (*.gpg) DO (call :subroutine %%f)
GOTO :eof
:subroutine
set filename=%1
echo %date% %time% - %filename% >> input_lst.log
gpg2 --q --batch --yes --passphrase-file "pwd.ini" -o %filename:~0,-4% -d %filename%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (DEL /Q /F "%filename%") ELSE GOTO :error
GOTO :eof 
:error 
echo %date% %time% - %filename% >> error.log 
:eof 
echo %date% %time% - %filename% >> processed.log
```

Now, the main task is to create a batch script (no need to specify any recipient, etc) that will encrypt files in L:\OUT  using the public key from external trusted source. Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Hi there! Formatting tip: the ` only works on single lines, to format a code block highlight your code in the question editor and either click the `{}` button or press `ctrl`+`k`.

Comment: No problem. By the way, you can take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a feel for the site, there are some great resources to get you started in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something, do it by yourself))

```
@echo off
FOR /R L:\OUT\ %%f in (*.txt) DO (call :subroutine %%f)
GOTO :eof
:subroutine
set filename=%1
echo %date% %time% - %filename% >> encr__input_lst.log
gpg2 -r trusted@domain.com --trust-model always -o %filename%.gpg --q --batch --yes -e %filename%
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (DEL /Q /F "%filename%") ELSE GOTO :error
GOTO :eof
:error
echo %date% %time% - %filename% >> encr_error.log
:eof
echo %date% %time% - %filename% >> encr_processed.log
```